# 2d Vector Of Classes, How To Reference

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator, segmentation-fault

Suppose I have :

```
class Intersection {
 public:
 int street;
 int avenue;
 double x;
 double y;
 double green[2];    // Light green times for STREET & AVENUE
 list <class Road_Segment *> adj;
 double best_time;
 class Road_Segment *backedge;
 multimap <double, Intersection *>::iterator bfsq_ptr;
 };
```

And in my main function I have a 2d vector of:

```
vector<vector<Intersection *> > vvin ; 
vector<vector<Intersection *> >::iterator vvit ;
```

And I am accessing it as such:

```
for (lit = City_Map::all.begin() ; lit != City_Map::all.end() ; lit++ ) {

inter = *lit ;
s = inter->street ;
a = inter->avenue ;
vvin[s][a] = inter ; 
}
```

Where lit is a list iterator that contains all the classes. I am having *difficulty* accessing the 2d vector via integer index, something of which I know I have done in the past. The program is segfaulting on that exact line. Any ideas why?

Also, even

```
cout << vvin[i][j] << endl ; // or for that matter[0][0] or [1][1] or whatever
```

segfaults, so I know it's not the pointer assignment.

If I am unable to access it via integer index, is there a way to use iterators in the same fashion so I can access it like a 2d array?

Please and thanks.

Comment: Your vectors are probably empty and so you're accessing out of bounds data.

Comment: nah, did the vvin.resize(100) and still segfaulted. Having to use .push_back(inter). Not what I wanted.

Comment: Did you resize both dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably accessing out of bounds. Try...

```
std::cout << "vvin.size() = " << vvin.size() << '\n';
for( size_t i = 0; i < vvin.size(); ++i )
{
    std::cout << "vvin[" << i << "].size() = " << vvin[i].size() << '\n';
}
```

Or set some breakpoints and inspect the vectors that way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a plenty of pointers seems really dangerous. It's very hard to track memory deallocation for all these pointers.

So at first try to use `vector<vector<Intersection> >;` to remove the possibility of an invalid pointer to the Intersection structure.

If the bug is not fixed, try this simple test to be sure that you have an element to address by 2 indices:

```
vector<vector<Intersection> > vvin;
vvin.push_back(vector<Intersection>());
vvin.back().push_back(Intersection());
cout << vvin[0][0] << endl;
```

If this code works normally (it must works normally!), it's obvious that you don't create an element you try to address by 2 indices.